# When to use Knex transacting() vs chaining off the trx object

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, transactions, knex.js

Knex's documentation for transactions has code that looks like this:

```
knex.transaction(function(trx) {
    var books = [
        {title: 'Canterbury Tales'},
        {title: 'Moby Dick'},
        {title: 'Hamlet'}
    ];

    return trx
    .insert({name: 'Old Books'}, 'id')
    .into('catalogues')
    .then(function(ids) {
    return Promise.map(books, function(book) {
        book.catalogue_id = ids[0];

        // Some validation could take place here.

        return trx.insert(info).into('books');
    });
    });
})
```

Here on SO I've seen extensive use of a function `transacting()` with examples that look like this:

```
knex.transaction(function(trx) {
   knex('foo')
  .transacting(trx)
  .insert({id:"bar", username:"bar"})
  // etc
 })
```

Knex describes `transacting()` with examples similar to above:

> Used by knex.transaction, the transacting method may be chained to any query and passed the object you wish to join the query as part of the transaction for.

**My question is:**

What is the difference between `trx.insert().into('foo')` and `knex('foo').transacting(trx).insert()` and why would you use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is convenient to use `.transacting(trx)` when you want to perform multiple operations in the same transaction:

```
knex.transaction(function (trx) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex('foo').insert({ name: 'My Name' }).transacting(trx),
        knex('bar').insert({ field: 'Value' }).transacting(trx)
    ])
    // ---- or something like ----
    return Promise.all(SOME_INPUT_VALUES.map(function (value) {
        return knex('foo_bar').update('lul', value.lul).where('id', value.id).transacting(trx)
    }))
})
```

Don't know really of a particular usage of the other method. It might be just a matter of style. You got two interfaces and you can pick one whatever you like most. As for me, I'm used to `.transacing(trx)`

Comment: It indeed is a matter of style. Using `.transacting()` is the old way and using `trx` like knex instance is new way. Latter way was added to make it harder to forget setting transaction for queries, which are pretty hard to spot bugs. So usually one should use `trx('table').insert(...)` style.